# Awaiting multiple async fn calls

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

## The problem

I have the following code, that spawns tasks inside a loop. At the end I want to await all tasks and add all results to a single collection:

```
pub async fn get_projects(organizations: &Vec<Organization>) -> Vec<Project> {
    // Define collection to hold the projects.
    let result: Vec<Project> = vec![];
    // Create a collection of tasks to retrieve the projects.
    let mut tasks = Vec::new();
    // Create a new task for each organization.
    for organization in organizations.iter() {
        if !organization.is_pat_valid {
            // If the PAT for the organization is not valid, do not try to retrieve the projects for it.
            continue;
        }
        // Create a new task to retrieve the projects for the organization and store it.
        tasks.push(tokio::spawn(repositories::devops::get_projects(
            &organization.pat,
            &organization.name,
        )))
    }
    // Wait for all tasks to finish.
    let task_results = join_all(tasks).await;
    // TODO: Add the projects from the resolved tasks all to the result collection.
    return result;
}
```

Internally I am using one of my repositories methods (spawned as task in the loop). See the fn definition for reference:

```
pub async fn get_projects(
    pat: &str,
    organization_name: &str,
) -> Result<Vec<Project>, reqwest::Error>
```

Now the compilier tells me the following error:

```
borrowed data escapes outside of function `organizations` escapes the function body here
```

## What I already tried

I tried creating copies of the values I need inside the loop

```
let pat = organization.pat.clone();
let organization_name = organization.name.clone();
```

I also tried then moving the spawn

```
tasks.push(tokio::task::spawn(async move {
            repositories::devops::get_projects(&organization.pat, &organization.name)
        }))
```

I was expecting to spawn one task for each given organization model. I expect that I can await all of this tasks later, get the Vec result from each task, add all projects to one Vec and return the whole thing.

Comment: I think you can just remove the `tokio::spawn` call to fix this problem. Tasks need `'static` lifetime but your tasks borrow from a function local.

Comment: I concur, it works if you omit `tokio::spawn`: [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9e1e09a7f804f5ac80d13e5f47d1013a)

Comment: It also works if you do *both* of your changes that you've already tried: [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=747da2b9cb2d7ff12872d08989c8814e)

Comment: Thank you @cdhowie. Removing `tokio::spawn` indeed was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to clone the `pat` and `organization_name`.
Try the following code:

```
use futures::future::join_all;

pub async fn get_projects(organizations: &Vec<Organization>) -> Vec<Project> {
    // Define collection to hold the projects.
    let mut result: Vec<Project> = vec![];
    // Create a collection of tasks to retrieve the projects.
    let mut tasks = Vec::new();
    // Create a new task for each organization.
    for organization in organizations.iter() {
        if !organization.is_pat_valid {
            // If the PAT for the organization is not valid, do not try to retrieve the projects for it.
            continue;
        }
        let pat = organization.pat.clone();
        let organization_name = organization.name.clone();
        // Create a new task to retrieve the projects for the organization and store it.
        tasks.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
            repositories::devops::get_projects(&pat, &organization_name).await
        }));
    }
    // Wait for all tasks to finish.
    let task_results = join_all(tasks).await;
    // TODO: Add the projects from the resolved tasks all to the result collection.

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the answer from @cdhowie already solved my problem.